# Different code in same controller action for html or json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I have a controller action that responds to the same root in two formats - html and json. But the code that runs for the html response is completely different than the one for the json response..
Now I have something like

```
def index
  result_html = ...
  result_json = ...
  respond_to |format|
     format.html
     format.json { result = result_json.limit(10) }
  end
end
```

and I would like to have it like

```
 def index.html
    result_html ...
 end
```

and

```
def index.json
  result_json ...
end
```

What would be the best way to organize it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be something like this will work for you.

```
def index
  respond_to |format|
     format.html { index_html}
     format.json { index_json }
  end
end

def index_html
  ...
end
def index_json
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can test for the format with `request.format.symbol` then `when :json` call your json action or `when :html` call your html action.